# Invalid Object Name ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

For some reason I keep on receiving an Invalid Object Name error when trying to make an entry to a table in the database.  This error began after adding a table to the database.  After adding the table to the database I updated Entity Framework by right clicking and updating from database.  I have read many posts referring to pluralization being the cause, however I do not believe that is the culprit in this case.  I'm pretty new to ASP.NET, what else could be causing this error?  Thanks, I will try to provide any information needed.

EDIT StackTrace

```
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at LogService60.ServiceObjects.BillingReport.SendToSQL() in C:\Utilities\LogParser\LogService60\ServiceObjects\Message.cs:line 144
```

Comment: What is the full exception message? Or is it only "Invalid Object Name"? Stack trace might help as well.

Comment: Could you also include the first line of the Stack Trace, the one with the exception type and message?

Comment: Edited original post to include the stacktrace

Comment: Well, sorry for wasting everyone's time.  Stupid mistake by me.  I forgot to change the connection string to point to the development server that I added the table to instead of the production server.

Answer (score 1):

I was too quick to post on here. Stupid mistake by me, I forgot to change the connection string in the config file to point to the development server that I changed the schema on. It was still pointing to the production server.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are refering to the correct name if you have a table name like `Persons` when you add it to the designer it will become `Person` so if you are querying the db like

```
   var person = from p in DBContext.Persons ....
```

it will give you the error

instead you should use

```
 var person = from p in DBContext.Person ....
```